# How to skip some lines from counting line numbers

Tags: codemirror

I am displaying some text in CodeMirror.
The requirement is:
For certain lines, I want to skip line numbers.
For example I want to display like this:

```
1  xxxxxx
   yyyyyy
2  zzzzzz
```

but instead the truth is:

```
1  xxxxxx
2  yyyyyy
3  zzzzzz
```

How can I achieve the effect above?

I have tried to write some code with setGutterMarker, but the thing is I could actually hide the line number but can't actually skip this line from counting.

```
addStyleToText() {
    const {
      editor: { doc }
    } = this.customTA;
    for (let i = 0; i < doc.lineCount(); i += 1) {
      if (doc.getLine(i).substr(0, 3) === 'ERR') {
        doc.addLineClass(i, 'background', 'error-info-line');
        doc.setGutterMarker(i, 'CodeMirror-linenumbers', this.makeMarker());
      }
    }
  }

  makeMarker() {
    var marker = document.createElement("div");
    marker.class="CodeMirror-linenumber CodeMirror-gutter-elt";
    marker.style.left = "0px";
    marker.style.width = "21px";
    marker.text = "";
    return marker;
  }
```

I want the ERR line to be not the part of the code. I don't want to count it in line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using i, set a counter variable before the for loop. Then, increment that counter only when desired.